# Asynchronous task runner

Tags: c#, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

This is my personal project.  This class is responsible for running jobs asynchronously that are registered using dependency injection.

All improvement suggestions are welcome. It can be as small as using a better name for a variable, re-architect the whole class, whatever. I'm just trying to improve myself.

[GitHub](https://github.com/kayone/NzbDrone/blob/master/NzbDrone.Core/Providers/Jobs/JobProvider.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Ninject;
using NLog;
using NzbDrone.Core.Model.Notification;
using NzbDrone.Core.Repository;
using PetaPoco;

namespace NzbDrone.Core.Providers.Jobs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a background task runner, tasks could be queue either by the scheduler using QueueScheduled()
    /// or by explicitly calling QueueJob(type,int)
    /// </summary>
    public class JobProvider
    {
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly IDatabase _database;
        private readonly NotificationProvider _notificationProvider;
        private readonly IList<IJob> _jobs;

        private static readonly object ExecutionLock = new object();
        private Thread _jobThread;
        private static bool _isRunning;

        private static readonly List<Tuple<Type, Int32>> _queue = new List<Tuple<Type, int>>();

        private ProgressNotification _notification;

        [Inject]
        public JobProvider(IDatabase database, NotificationProvider notificationProvider, IList<IJob> jobs)
        {
            _database = database;
            _notificationProvider = notificationProvider;
            _jobs = jobs;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="JobProvider"/> class. by AutoMoq
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Should only be used by AutoMoq</remarks>
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public JobProvider() { }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the active queue.
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Tuple<Type, Int32>> Queue
        {
            get
            {
                return _queue;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of all registered jobs
        /// </summary>
        public virtual List<JobDefinition> All()
        {
            return _database.Fetch<JobDefinition>().ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds/Updates definitions for a job
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="definitions">Settings to be added/updated</param>
        public virtual void SaveDefinition(JobDefinition definitions)
        {
            if (definitions.Id == 0)
            {
                Logger.Trace("Adding job definitions for {0}", definitions.Name);
                _database.Insert(definitions);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Trace("Updating job definitions for {0}", definitions.Name);
                _database.Update(definitions);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Iterates through all registered jobs and queues any that are due for an execution.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Will ignore request if queue is already running.</remarks>
        public virtual void QueueScheduled()
        {
            lock (ExecutionLock)
            {
                if (_isRunning)
                {
                    Logger.Trace("Queue is already running. Ignoring scheduler's request.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var counter = 0;

            var pendingJobs = All().Where(
                t => t.Enable &&
                     (DateTime.Now - t.LastExecution) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(t.Interval)
                ).Select(c => _jobs.Where(t => t.GetType().ToString() == c.TypeName).Single());

            foreach (var job in pendingJobs)
            {
                QueueJob(job.GetType());
                counter++;
            }

            Logger.Trace("{0} Scheduled tasks have been added to the queue", counter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Queues the execution of a job asynchronously
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jobType">Type of the job that should be queued.</param>
        /// <param name="targetId">The targetId could be any Id parameter eg. SeriesId. it will be passed to the job implementation
        /// to allow it to filter it's target of execution.</param>
        /// <remarks>Job is only added to the queue if same job with the same targetId doesn't already exist in the queue.</remarks>
        public virtual void QueueJob(Type jobType, int targetId = 0)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Adding [{0}:{1}] to the queue", jobType.Name, targetId);

            lock (ExecutionLock)
            {
                lock (Queue)
                {
                    var queueTuple = new Tuple<Type, int>(jobType, targetId);

                    if (!Queue.Contains(queueTuple))
                    {
                        Queue.Add(queueTuple);
                        Logger.Trace("Job [{0}:{1}] added to the queue", jobType.Name, targetId);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Logger.Info("[{0}:{1}] already exists in the queue. Skipping.", jobType.Name, targetId);
                    }
                }

                if (_isRunning)
                {
                    Logger.Trace("Queue is already running. No need to start it up.");
                    return;
                }
                _isRunning = true;
            }

            if (_jobThread == null || !_jobThread.IsAlive)
            {
                Logger.Trace("Initializing queue processor thread");

                ThreadStart starter = () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ProcessQueue();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logger.ErrorException("Error has occurred in queue processor thread", e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _isRunning = false;
                    }
                };

                _jobThread = new Thread(starter) { Name = "JobQueueThread" };
                _jobThread.Start();

            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Error("Execution lock has fucked up. Thread still active. Ignoring request.");
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts processing of queue synchronously.
        /// </summary>
        private void ProcessQueue()
        {
            do
            {
                Tuple<Type, int> job = null;

                using (NestedDiagnosticsContext.Push(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        lock (Queue)
                        {
                            if (Queue.Count != 0)
                            {
                                job = Queue.First();
                            }
                        }

                        if (job != null)
                        {
                            Execute(job.Item1, job.Item2);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logger.FatalException("An error has occurred while processing queued job.", e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (job != null)
                        {
                            Queue.Remove(job);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } while (Queue.Count != 0);

            Logger.Trace("Finished processing jobs in the queue.");

            return;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the job synchronously
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jobType">Type of the job that should be executed</param>
        /// <param name="targetId">The targetId could be any Id parameter eg. SeriesId. it will be passed to the timer implementation
        /// to allow it to filter it's target of execution</param>
        private void Execute(Type jobType, int targetId = 0)
        {
            var jobImplementation = _jobs.Where(t => t.GetType() == jobType).Single();
            if (jobImplementation == null)
            {
                Logger.Error("Unable to locate implementation for '{0}'. Make sure it is properly registered.", jobType);
                return;
            }

            var settings = All().Where(j => j.TypeName == jobType.ToString()).Single();

            using (_notification = new ProgressNotification(jobImplementation.Name))
            {
                try
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Starting '{0}' job. Last execution {1}", settings.Name, settings.LastExecution);

                    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    _notificationProvider.Register(_notification);
                    jobImplementation.Start(_notification, targetId);
                    _notification.Status = ProgressNotificationStatus.Completed;

                    settings.LastExecution = DateTime.Now;
                    settings.Success = true;

                    sw.Stop();
                    Logger.Debug("Job '{0}' successfully completed in {1}.{2} seconds.", jobImplementation.Name, sw.Elapsed.Seconds, sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 100,
                                sw.Elapsed.Seconds);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.ErrorException("An error has occurred while executing job " + jobImplementation.Name, e);
                    _notification.Status = ProgressNotificationStatus.Failed;
                    _notification.CurrentMessage = jobImplementation.Name + " Failed.";

                    settings.LastExecution = DateTime.Now;
                    settings.Success = false;
                }
            }

            //Only update last execution status if was triggered by the scheduler
            if (targetId == 0)
            {
                SaveDefinition(settings);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes jobs in the database using the IJob instances that are
        /// registered using ninject
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Initialize()
        {
            Logger.Debug("Initializing jobs. Count {0}", _jobs.Count());
            var currentTimer = All();

            foreach (var timer in _jobs)
            {
                var timerProviderLocal = timer;
                if (!currentTimer.Exists(c => c.TypeName == timerProviderLocal.GetType().ToString()))
                {
                    var settings = new JobDefinition
                                       {
                                           Enable = timerProviderLocal.DefaultInterval > 0,
                                           TypeName = timer.GetType().ToString(),
                                           Name = timerProviderLocal.Name,
                                           Interval = timerProviderLocal.DefaultInterval,
                                           LastExecution = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
                                       };

                    SaveDefinition(settings);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the next scheduled run time for a specific job
        /// (Estimated due to schedule timer)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>DateTime of next scheduled job execution</returns>
        public virtual DateTime NextScheduledRun(Type jobType)
        {
            var job = All().Where(t => t.TypeName == jobType.ToString()).Single();
            return job.LastExecution.AddMinutes(job.Interval);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to focus your review question to a particular area. See FAQ: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#make-sure-you-include-your-code-in-your-question

Answer (score 2):

Taking the processqueue part....  I'd do something like :-

```
        private void ExecuteJob(Tuple<Type,int> job)
        {
            try
            {                
                Execute(job.Item1, job.Item2);                
            }            
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (NestedDiagnosticsContext.Push(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
                {
                    Logger.FatalException("An error has occurred while processing queued job.", e);
                }
            }

        }

        private void ProcessQueue()
        {            
            List<Tuple<Type, int>> jobs;
            lock (Queue)
            {
               jobs = Queue.ToList();
               Queue.Clear();                
            }
            jobs.ForEach(ExecuteJob);                                                    
            Logger.Trace("Finished processing jobs in the queue.");
        }
```

This means you only lock once  ( you have a bug in that you don't lock when you remove),  your try catch is finer grained, your using is finer grained.

But the I'd probably turn the tuple into a Class.  The rest of the code has similar issues.